# How to create custom type in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can some one explain how to create our own custom types in angular using typescript syntax. Please provide example as well. 
Thanks!

Comment: outside of simple types, most types are simply class declaration, as with most compiled OO languages: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by `type` exactly.

If you want to define a "type" that you can use in TypeScript strong typing, then you have several choices.

You can build an interface like this:

```
export interface Product {
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  releaseDate: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

And use it as a type like this:

```
const products: Product[] = [];
```

Or as mentioned in the comments, you can build a TypeScript class:

```
export class Product {
  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  releaseDate: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

And use it similarly. With a class, you can "new" up instances, which you can't do with an interface.

EDIT 12/28/21:
Angular by default now has strict typing on by default. This means that there is a bit more work to do when declaring a class with a set of properties. Each property must be changed using one of these techniques:

- Add  `| undefined` to the type
- Add a default value such as  `= ''`
- Use the definite assignment assertion operator (`!`), which denotes that you will take care to definitely assign it sometime later.
- Make the property optional using the `?`

Here is an example that uses each of the above:

```
export class Product {
  productId: number | undefined;
  productName = '';
  productCode!: string;
  releaseDate?: string;
  price?: number;
  description?: string;
  starRating?: number;
  imageUrl?: string;
}
```

Comment: Note in newer versions of typescript the `export class` syntax shown here will lead to compilier warnings.  See https://tutorial.tips/3-ways-to-fix-property-has-no-initializer-and-is-not-definitely-assigned-in-the-constructorts/ for what to do about it