# HttpClient: how to show data on DOM

Tags: javascript, angular

This is an employee list from my mock `db.json`. I am trying to visualise it in the `DOM`.
In the `app.component.html` if I write in the loop `{{employee}}`, it visualises a list of 2 items and each item is`[object Object]`. Otherwise if I write `{{employee.name}}` the error is:
`Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EmployeeService'.ngtsc(2339)`

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.Thank you.

`app.component.html`:

```html
{{title}}

<li *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{employee.name}}</li> //error with property name
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './service/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'List of employees';

employees: EmployeeService[]=[];

constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.employeeService.getUsers().subscribe(emp => {
this.employees = emp;
  }) 
}
}
```

`employee.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<EmployeeService[]> {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeService[]>('http://localhost:3000/employees')
  }

}
```

`db.json`:

```js
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tim",
      "hired": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Jess",
      "hired": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you log the value in `this.employees` and share?

Comment: from app.component.ts 
`ngOnInit(): void {...
console.log(this.employees)}`
The result is:
`(2) [{…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: Return type is wrong `this.http.get<EmployeeService[]>`, it should return custom dataType instead of `EmployeeService[]` itself.

Comment: @Sateesh do you mean the `interface` type?

Comment: You can check this url for custom types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332832/how-to-create-custom-type-in-angular or you can use `any[]` to support any data type

Comment: Yes, I mean `interface`

Comment: Change type here also `employees: EmployeeService[]=[];` if it's not working then let me know.

Comment: in `app.component.ts` employees: `EmployeeService[]=[]`; changed into employees: `EmployeeInterface[]=[]`;
in employee.service.ts:   `getUsers(): Observable<EmployeeService[]> {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeService[]>('http://localhost:3000/employees')` changed into
  `getUsers(): Observable<EmployeeInterface[]> {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeInterface[]>('http://localhost:3000/employees')` 
IT WORKED!!! THANKS, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always see the data loaded to the template file using the json pipe operator,

**Example** `<div>{{employees | json }}</div>` , this will help you to understand the structure of data and access it correctly.

**Solution to your problem:**

The response from your `getUsers()` returns an object, that contains an array for employees. You were trying to access the data object.

Instead, you should retrieve the `employees` data from the object and loop through the `employees` data in your template file.

**In your `app.component.ts` component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './service/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'List of employees';

employees: any[]=[]; // preferably a custom type/interface than 'any'

constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
this.employeeService.getUsers().subscribe(emp => {
this.employees = emp.employees;  // ------------------> Change
  }) 
}
}
```

**Inside your `app.component.html` template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{ employee.name }}</div>
```

In your `employee.service.ts` service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Your custom interface/type should be the return type 
  getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/employees');
  }

}
```

Working app in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qju5bp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: when it is changed into `this.employees = emp.employees;` it throws error:  `Property 'employees' does not exist on type 'EmployeeService[]'.ts(2339)`

Comment: can you tell me why are you creating an array with your service as type? `employees: EmployeeService[]=[];`

Comment: If you don't have a type defined for the data in the response, try changing to `employees: any[]=[];`

Comment: I have updated my answer with the changes, please try that.

Comment: It has worked, but what shall I do in `employee.service.ts`?:
  `getUsers(): Observable<EmployeeService[]> {
    return this.http.get<EmployeeService[]>('http://localhost:3000/employees')`

Comment: I have decided to add an `interface` also. thank you for you help

Comment: Yes. adding an interface/Type is always a good idea

Comment: added the modification for your service file too

Answer (score 0):

```
// check whether the employee list is not empty before rendering it in UI
<ul *ngIf="employees">
  <li *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{ employee.name }}</li>
</ul>


// To view complete JSON dump in web page follow below: Add this import statement to your app module

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

then include it in imports 

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [CommonModule, ...],
})

<!-- in your app.html: -->

<div *ngIf ="employees">
   {{ employees | json}}
</div>
```